# Visual Studio 17.7.4 iOS Brooker connection problem with macOS Ventura

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Visual Studio Community won't connect with macOS.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiEp1.png)

'An error occured while registering a handler for remote exception messages, so the remote errors content will not be handled in this active connection.'

The preliminary checks go through but I'm getting the above error each time. I've cleared the Brooker Caches (XMA) on both Windows and macOS but nothing has changed.

Anyone getting this error with the latest versions of Visual Studio. VS 2022 Preview doesn't make a difference either and the xamarin.ios is up to date.

Thanks

Comment: Close VS and clear `bin` & `obj` folder of project. Then reopen VS to see if it works well. If not, please try to  [clear the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac), and re-pair to Mac.

Comment: Hello @JianweiSun-MSFT thanks for your reply. I've tried you suggestion and even reinstalled macOS/intalled XCODE etc. Unfotuntely I'm still getting the error. I'm currently runing Visual Studio 17.4 LTSC and this seems to be working but occasionally I'm getting the same error. Once connected VS will keep dropping the mac connection and retrying.

Comment: Maybe this is an internal networking issue.

Comment: *“Maybe this is an internal networking issue.”* It seems like this.

Comment: Hi, Installing Visual Studio Preview 17.8.0 seems to stop the problem. Or, perhaps the recent XCode 15 release. The join is still a bit dodgy though and occasionally I receive IDB errors.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT Clearing the bin/obj and Broker cache made no difference and the error still occurs.

Comment: Maybe it is an issue. You can [report it to GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Answer (score 0):

According to your reply, as an answer.

When pair to Mac, if it occurs this error:

'An error occured while registering a handler for remote exception messages, so the remote errors content will not be handled in this active connection.'

We can try to use Visual Studio 17.4 LTSC to fix the the problem. BTW, pay attention to network connection.

Answer (score 0):

As @user22551953 suggested, upgrading to v17.8.0 preview 2 seems to fix the issue.